# convert java timestamp string to java timestamp object

Tags: java, date, timezone-offset, java.time.instant, datetimeformatter

I have following timestamp string `"2021010112:12:12.10:00"` and I want to convert it to `java.time.Instant`.

The issue in parsing string through `DateTimeFormatter` is due to absence of time zone sign before last 4 digits. Logically it is `yyyyMMddHH:mm:ss.` and `10:00` is time zone offset e.g `UTC+10:00`, but issue is it does not have sign.

How can I parse this string to `Instant` object?

Comment: Can't you just add the region to the date string?

Comment: *and 10:00 is time zone offset* How would Java know whether that offset were negative or positive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not very elegant, but you could `split` the input by a dot. That would separate the datetime part from the offset and you can concatenate the desired (and required) sign with the value.

**This requires you to know which sign to apply! The code cannot guess it...**

Maybe write a method that takes this input `String` and a sign to be applied as arguments.

Since it seems not possible to parse an unsigned `String` representation of an offset, you would need something like the following:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String timestamp = "2021010112:12:12.10:00";
    // provide a formatter that parses the datetime (the part before the dot)
    DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuuMMddHH:mm:ss");
    // split the timestamp String by the dot to separate datetime from offset
    String[] split = timestamp.split("\\.");
    // parse the datetime part using the formatter defined above
    LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse(split[0], dtf);
    // and build up an offset using offset part adding a plus sign
    ZoneOffset zoneOffset = ZoneOffset.of("+" + split[1]);
    // then create an OffsetDateTime from the LocalDateTime and the ZoneOffset
    OffsetDateTime result = OffsetDateTime.of(ldt, zoneOffset);
    // finally get an Instant from it
    Instant instant = result.toInstant();  // <--- INSTANT HERE
    // and print the values
    System.out.println(result + " = " + instant.toEpochMilli());
}
```

This outputs

```
2021-01-01T12:12:12+10:00 = 1609467132000
```

Comment: *// and build up an offset using offset part adding a plus sign* How would you know you *can* assume a plus sign?

Comment: @g00se I can't... Probably nobody can, but OP could use this example to create a method that passes the `String` and the desired sign. If OP wants the code to *guess* the sign, there won't be any possibility of it guessing right in every single case.

Answer (score 2):

The [answer by deHaar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68983417/10819573) is correct. This answer shows an easier way of solving this problem.

You can use the [regex](https://regex101.com/r/N6uCRZ/1), `(\.)(\d{1,2}:\d{1,2})` to replace the `.` (group#1 in the regex) before the timezone offset part (group#2 in the regex) with a `+`.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String strDateTime = "2021010112:12:12.10:00";
        strDateTime = strDateTime.replaceFirst("(\\.)(\\d{1,2}:\\d{1,2})", "+$2");

        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuuMMddHH:mm:ssXXX", Locale.ENGLISH);
        Instant instant = OffsetDateTime.parse(strDateTime, dtf).toInstant();
        System.out.println(instant);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2021-01-01T02:12:12Z
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/AgH5P3)

Alternatively, you can use the [regex](https://regex101.com/r/vw2g6H/1), `\.(\d{1,2}:\d{1,2})` and prepend group#1 with a `+` sign. Note that the `DateTimeFormatter` needs to be adjusted accordingly.

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String strDateTime = "2021010112:12:12.10:00";
        strDateTime = strDateTime.replaceFirst("\\.(\\d{1,2}:\\d{1,2})", ".+$1");

        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuuMMddHH:mm:ss.XXX", Locale.ENGLISH);
        Instant instant = OffsetDateTime.parse(strDateTime, dtf).toInstant();
        System.out.println(instant);
    }
}
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/Hw6YKV)

The benefits of using this alternative solution is as described in the following comment by Ole V.V.:

> Just speculating, maybe a minus sign would be present in case of a
> negative UTC offset. If so, maybe use
> `strDateTime.replaceFirst("\\.(\\d{1,2}:\\d{1,2})", ".+$1")` to obtain
> 2021010112:12:12.+10:00 in the positive offset case, after which both
> positive and negative offset (and zero) could be parsed.

Comment: Just speculating, maybe a minus sign would be present in case of a negative UTC offset. If so, maybe use `strDateTime.replaceFirst("\\.(\\d{1,2}:\\d{1,2})", ".+$1")` to obtain `2021010112:12:12.+10:00` in the positive offset case, after which both positive and negative offset (and zero) could be parsed.

Comment: @OleV.V. - What a co-incidence! I had done exactly this way in my first attempt but before posting it finally, I changed my mind. Let me post it as an alternative solution.

Answer (score 2):

### ParsePosition

There are two good answers already. Here’s my suggestion.

```
    String timestampString = "2021010112:12:12.10:00";
    
    ParsePosition position = new ParsePosition(0);
    TemporalAccessor parsed = PARSER.parse(timestampString, position);
    LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.from(parsed);
    
    String offsetString = timestampString.substring(position.getIndex());
    if (Character.isDigit(offsetString.charAt(0))) { // no sign
        offsetString = "+" + offsetString;
    }
    ZoneOffset offset = ZoneOffset.of(offsetString);
    
    Instant timestamp = dateTime.atOffset(offset).toInstant();
    
    System.out.println(timestamp);
```

Output:

> 2021-01-01T02:12:12Z

The downside is the use of the `TemporalAccessor` interface, a low-level interface that we should not normally use in application code. The upsides include that the code accepts strings with and without sign before the offset and we don’t need any split operation or other application of regular expressions. If the UTC offset is negative, the sign must be there, or we can’t tell. Let’s also try this:

```
    String timestampString = "2021010112:12:12.-10:00";
```

> 2021-01-01T22:12:12Z

I believe that the `ParsePosition` class is the only class from the old `java.text` package that is reused in java.time, which I personally find curious.